# Appending array in a cycle

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists like in the example below:

```
result_primary = ['00000000', '01010101', '10101010', '11111111']
result_compressed =  ['01100110', '10011001']
```

I am calculating the hamming distance between each element from the second list and each element from the first. For that purpose I have the following code:

```
def hamming2(s1, s2):
    assert len(s1) == len(s2)
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))


for i in result_primary:
    for j in result_compressed:
        primary_att_vs_compr_hamming = np.array([i, j, hamming2(i, j)] )

        print(primary_att_vs_compr_hamming)
```

This gives me the desired outcome at the console:

```
['00000000' '01100110' '4']
['00000000' '10011001' '4']
['01010101' '01100110' '4']
['01010101' '10011001' '4']
['10101010' '01100110' '4']
['10101010' '10011001' '4']
['11111111' '01100110' '4']
['11111111' '10011001' '4']
```

But actually I do not have all the data captured in the array, instead the cycle overwrites the variable in each iteration and at the end I have only the last row written in the array:

```
   def hamming2(s1, s2):
        assert len(s1) == len(s2)
        return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
    
    
    for i in result_primary:
        for j in result_compressed:
            primary_att_vs_compr_hamming = np.array([i, j, hamming2(i, j)] )
    
    print(primary_att_vs_compr_hamming)
```

Output:

```
['11111111' '10011001' '4']
```

How can I make it to write everything in the array (as I am willing to have it for further manipulations? Also, how can I put titles of the columns in the array (anyway it is array of strings)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use strings for that? Hamming distance is slower that way. And more importantly, you can't vectorize (which is the whole point of numpy arrays. And you tagged the question "numpy". Currently, you have no benefit at all of using numpy, and you would be better of using a pure python list)

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I will take care to convert it to array of integers accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an external list to store results:

```
data = []
for i in result_primary:
    for j in result_compressed:
        primary_att_vs_compr_hamming = np.array([i, j, hamming2(i, j)])
        data.append(primary_att_vs_compr_hamming)
```

Output:

```
>>> np.array(data)
array([['00000000', '01100110', '4'],
       ['00000000', '10011001', '4'],
       ['01010101', '01100110', '4'],
       ['01010101', '10011001', '4'],
       ['10101010', '01100110', '4'],
       ['10101010', '10011001', '4'],
       ['11111111', '01100110', '4'],
       ['11111111', '10011001', '4']], dtype='<U21')
```